# React received `true` for a non-boolean attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just check this condition to set class on a element, but get this error:

```
<div className={(this.state.kindValue === 1 && this.state.depositValue === 1) || (this.state.depositValue === 0 ? 'two fields' : 'two fields hide')}>
```

> index.js:1406 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute
>   `className`.
>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead:
>   className="true" or className={value.toString()}.

I can't understand what should I solvet this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you put brackets incorrectly so you get `true` or `false` instead of `two fields` or `two fields hide`. Try this code instead

```
<div className={(this.state.kindValue === 1 && this.state.depositValue === 1) || this.state.depositValue === 0 ? 'two fields' : 'two fields hide'}>
```